# Is there a way to embed imported json data in the published build package

Tags: json, angular, typescript, npm

I have a publishable angular library that has a dependency on a json file that's imported from a private npm directory (requires vpn access). I would like to configure my build process so that it can embed the imported data, thus eliminating the dependency (and the need for the private vpn) in the published package. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can use "bundledDependencies" in your `package.json`, which will cause `npm pack` it include the dependency files in your tarball.

Comment: @Pointy appreciate the response. Still getting a dependency error but I think that got me on the right path. Looks like I might need to change out output directory so I  can use pack instead of doing a manual tar

Comment: Yea `npm pack` is almost a manual `tar`, but it puts everything in a "package" top-level directory. If you set `bundleDependencies` to simply `true` then it will bundle everything, but that may be a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can import json like this:

```
import appsettings from './../../../settings.json';
```

Comment: importing json wasn't the problem. Problem was (like the title says) how to EMBED imported json in the build package, thus not including the original source at all